# How to resample and interpolate (cubic spline) timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, resampling

I need to resample timeseries to a fixed interval eg. 3 months and at the same time interpolate with the cubic spline method.
What would be the most efficient way?
sample data:

```
dates = ('2020-09-24','2020-10-19','2020-12-17','2021-03-17','2021-06-17','2021-09-17','2022-03-17','2022-09-20','2023-09-19','2024-09-17','2025-09-17','2026-09-17','2027-09-17','2028-09-19','2029-09-18','2030-09-17','2031-09-17','2032-09-17','2035-09-18','2040-09-18','2045-09-19')
factors = ('1','0.999994','0.999875','1.000166','1.000303','1.000438','1.00056','1.000817','1.001046','1.001412','1.001525','1.001334','1.000685','0.999376','0.997456','0.994626','0.991244','0.986754','0.982072','0.962028','0.925136')
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['dates']=dates
df['factors']=factors
```

Comment: How you want to resample (i.e. `sum` or `mean`?)

Comment: @Grayrigel the idea is to start with the first date and move along with 3 months intervals.

Comment: I understand that. However, what if you have multiple entries within the 3 months period for `factors` then you want to sum them, mean them, count them?  Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

dates = ('2020-09-24','2020-10-19','2020-12-17','2021-03-17','2021-06-17','2021-09-17','2022-03-17','2022-09-20','2023-09-19','2
024-09-17','2025-09-17','2026-09-17','2027-09-17','2028-09-19','2029-09-18','2030-09-17','2031-09-17','2032-09-17','2035-09-18',
'2040-09-18','2045-09-19')
factors = ('1','0.999994','0.999875','1.000166','1.000303','1.000438','1.00056','1.000817','1.001046','1.001412','1.001525','1.0
01334','1.000685','0.999376','0.997456','0.994626','0.991244','0.986754','0.982072','0.962028','0.925136')
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['dates']=dates
df['factors']=factors


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['dates']=dates
df['factors']=factors

df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
df.set_index(['dates'],inplace=True)
df['factors']  = df['factors'].astype(float)

df = df.resample('3MS', loffset=timedelta(days=df.index[0].day - 1 )).mean().interpolate(method='cubic')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
dates               
2020-09-24  0.999997
2020-12-24  0.999875
2021-03-24  1.000166
2021-06-24  1.000303
2021-09-24  1.000438
...              ...
2044-09-24  0.933154
2044-12-24  0.931170
2045-03-24  0.929196
2045-06-24  0.927170
2045-09-24  0.925136
```

Comment: Thx @Grayriegel,  I have changed to mean(). Is is possible to start with the original date and not month end?

Comment: @user3087494 I have updated my answer. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: @Grairiegel, thanks for that however the last challenge is to align the start date with the original date. Now it's start of the month. Any idea much appreciated

Comment: Thanks @Grayrigel, this is what I thought as well. For a now it must be a solution. The downside of that solution is that with 90D we are not splitting equally our year in quarters and this is more visible in the long horizon. That should be ok for a now, however if you have any other solution that would be even better. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Graygiel, another approach could be generate a new dataframe with the timeseries with the fixed interval of 3M and then update the new column with the interpolated values from the original dataframe?Would it be possible?

Comment: @MBu I have updated my answer with `loffset`. Sure, that can be done. However, I think that is same as offset.